# Cmake - cant link library glfw3

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw

I am running ubuntu 22.04.

I have done this:

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libglfw3-dev is already the newest version (3.3.6-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
```

In my main CMakeLists.txt I have this:

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(X11 REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)

include_directories(${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${X11_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(/usr/include/GLFW)
```

Than Cmake output gives me this:

```
-- Found GLFW: /usr/include (found version "3.3.6")
```

Looks like it's finds the library. So far so good.

Than in my WorldServer target CMakeLists.txt I have this:

```
target_link_libraries(WorldServer PUBLIC
        Common
        ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        ${X11_LIBRARIES}
        ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
        glfw3
        Xxf86vm
        Xcursor
        gRPC::grpc++
        gRPC::grpc++_reflection
        VibraniumEngine
        Irrlicht
        )
```

Above is just the snippet I use to try to link to the library. Everything else in both CMakeLists.txt is unrelated with the problem I have and the problem is:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/WorldServer
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/build.make:1648: bin/WorldServer] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:384: Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:391: Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:195: WorldServer] Error 2
```

As far as I can understand WorldServer target is unable to link against glfw3 library.
Why is that and how can I fix it ?

Comment: The output `-- Found GLFW: /usr/include` is NOT from the `glfw3Config.cmake` script, which is part of [libglfw3-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libglfw3-dev/filelist) package: when config file is used, CMake prints directory with that file. It seems that output is from `FindGLFW.cmake` script, which **your** ship with your project and add directory with that script into `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable. Consult that script about proper usage of its results. E.g. the line `include_directories(/usr/include/GLFW)` definitely doesn't use results of that script.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue and I am running Ubuntu 22.04 as well. Strange.

Comment: I would expect that explicitly linking glfw3 (or glfw) is not required at all if you're already linking ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} - if find_package did its job that variable should contain all libraries you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
target_link_libraries(WorldServer PUBLIC
        ...
        glfw
        ...
        )
```

There should be no 3 in `glfw`